# Sum function in XSL

Tags: xslt

The Below is my input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LogiusInhouse>
    <qty9 field="QTY_9,11#">
        <type>90</type>
        <value>12</value>
    </qty9>
    <qty9 field="QTY_9,11#">
        <type>90</type>
        <value>12</value>
    </qty9>
    <dtm9 field="DTM_9,11#">
        <type>145</type>
        <date>20130308</date>
        <format>102</format>
    </dtm9>
</LogiusInhouse>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/LogiusInhouse">

        <xsl:value-of select="abs(sum(qty9[type='90']/value))div 1000 "/>

</xsl:template>
```

my problem is i need to get the absolute sum afterthat it has to be divided by 1000 but iam not getting the result.Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, you can use just this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/LogiusInhouse">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(qty9/value)" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i have to add the values and the value should be absolute so that we can remove + and - sign and then it should be divided by 1000.

Answer (score 2):

do not use for-each. use the template below

```
<xsl:template match="/LogiusInhouse">               
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//value)"/>                                     
</xsl:template>
```

using for-each will output `1212` because for-each node (in your code), the result is `12`

Comment: Or even given the XML provided: `<xsl:value-of select="sum(//qty9/value)"/>` which would target more specifically what to sum. Or even `"LogiusInhouse/qty9/value"`.

Comment: Good solution, if you bear in mind that `//` selects nodes _anywhere_ in the stylesheet, not just descendants of `LogiusInhouse`. For the XML file in question it does not matter of course.